# Stop Watch class in C++ using chrono

Tags: c++, datetime

I have written a class that acts like a stopwatch using C++11's `std::chrono` library. I wrote this because I find it difficult to benchmark my cpp code properly, this class just combines chrono's functionality and gives it a nice interface

I have two classes, `stopwatch.h` and `lapwatch.h`. The second one has the functionality of a stop watch but also has a lap function which you can use to multiple intervals

### `stopwatch.h`

```cpp
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H_
#define STOPWATCH_H_
#include <chrono>

template<typename duration = std::chrono::milliseconds>
class StopWatch
{
public:
  using clock      = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<clock, duration>;

  StopWatch() = default;
protected:
  enum class State : unsigned char;

  static constexpr time_point current_time() noexcept
  {
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<duration>(clock::now());
  }
public:
  virtual void reset() noexcept
  {
    clock_state = State::idle;
  }

  time_point go() noexcept
  {
    if (clock_state != State::stopped)
      start_point = current_time();

    clock_state = State::running;
    return start_point;
  }

  void stop() noexcept
  {
    if (clock_state == State::running)
    {
      stop_point = current_time();
      clock_state = State::stopped;
    }
  }

  duration elapsed_time() const noexcept
  {
    switch (clock_state)
    {
    case State::idle:
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(clock::duration::zero());

    case State::running:
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(current_time() - start_point);

    case State::stopped:
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(stop_point - start_point);

    default:
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(clock::duration::zero());
      break;
    }
  }

protected:
  enum class State : unsigned char { idle, running, stopped };

  time_point start_point;
  time_point stop_point;
  State      clock_state = State::idle;
};
```

---

### `lapwatch.h`

```cpp
  
#ifndef LAPWATCH_H_
#define LAPWATCH_H_
#include "stopwatch.h"
#include <vector>

template<typename duration = std::chrono::milliseconds>
class LapWatch : public StopWatch<duration>
{
  using clock      = typename StopWatch<duration>::clock;
  using time_point = typename StopWatch<duration>::clock;
  using StopWatch<duration>::State;
  
public:
  LapWatch() = default;
  struct Lap
  {
    duration total_time;
    duration split_time;
  };

  void lap() 
  {
    if (this->clock_state != StopWatch<duration>::State::running)
      return;

    Lap current;
    if (laps.size() == 0)
      current.total_time = current.split_time = StopWatch<duration>::elapsed_time();
    else
    {
      current.total_time = StopWatch<duration>::elapsed_time();
      current.split_time = (current.total_time - laps[laps.size() - 1].total_time);
    }
    laps.push_back(static_cast<Lap&&>(current));
  }

  void reset() noexcept
  {
    laps.clear();
  }

  std::vector<Lap> laps;
};
#endif // !LAPWATCH_H_
```

---

### usage example

```cpp
#include "lapwatch.h"

int main()
{
  LapWatch<> watch;
  
  watch.go() // start the timer
  // Some time passes
  
  watch.lap() // Adds the total and split time, but doesn't stop it
  
  // Some more time passes
  watch.lap() // Adds another lap

  watch.stop() // stop the watch now
  
  // Laps are added to a vector in watch.laps
  
  for(auto const& lap : watch.laps) {
    lap.total_time // Total time passed since the start
    lap.split_time // Total time passed since the previous lap
  }
}
```

### Concerns

- Is this a good idea? Would you use it?
- Is this a nice design?

---

I have a github [repository](https://github.com/Aryan1508/StopWatch-cpp) for it too, if anyone prefers reading code that way.

Comment: Calling `LapWatch::reset` does not reset the `clock_state` in the base class to `idle`. Is this intended?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm no! made a mistake there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use `clock`'s native resolution everywhere

If you cast time points and durations to something with a different resolution than that of `clock`, you risk losing precision. So for all internal state of your classes, I would definitely store everything as `clock::duration` and `clock::time_point` types. You might consider keeping the template parameter to ensure the return types of public member functions have the requested time resolution, but that just makes it easy for the caller to make the same mistake.

To give an example of where it can go wrong, suppose I write:

```
StopWatch<std::chrono::seconds> watch;
watch.go(); // done at 11:59:59.999
...
watch.stop(); // done at 12:00:00.000
auto elapsed = watch.elapsed_time();
```

With your implementation, `elapsed` will be equal to one second, even though only one millisecond passed.

If the issue is just convenience so the caller doesn't have to call `std::chrono::duration_cast<>()` themselves, I would remove the template parameter from the `class`, and make the member function `elapsed_time()` a template instead, like so:

```
template <typename duration = clock::duration>
duration elapsed_time() const noexcept
{
    ...
}
```

## `current_time()` should not be `constexpr`

If you mark a function [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), you promise that this function can be evaluated at compile-time. But that does not make sense here.

## Consider not storing lap results in `LapWatch`

Having `struct Lap` and a function to mark when a lap happened is good. However, by making `lap()` store the results in a member variable, you now gave `LapWatch` the responsibility to store laps. That might sometimes be exactly what you want, but maybe the caller wants to do something completely different. Maybe the previous laps don't need to be stored, or they need to be stored in a different way. I would make `lap()` return a `Lap` instead, and have the caller decide whether it wants to add those to some container. So:

```
Lap lap() {
    Lap current;
    ...
    return current;
}
```

And then the caller can write:

```
LapWatch<> watch;
std:vector<Lap> laps;
laps.push_back(watch.lap());
```

## Use `std::move()` instead of `static_cast<Lap&&>()`

If you really want to move an object, use [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), it is shorter and less error-prone.

Note that neither the cast nor `std::move()` will do anything in this case, since neither `Lap` nor `std::chrono::duration` has a move constructor, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Also consider RAII and removing the `go` and `stop` functions.

Comment: Thank you for the review, are you sure about your first point( loss of precision)? I tried out your example but it gives the expected answer

Comment: What you're saying about laps makes sense, but if I didn't have hold of the laps, how do I store the split time? Time elapsed between two laps

Comment: Ah hm, I didn't realize that `std::chrono::hours` actually has seconds resolution.

Comment: As for the split time: you only need to remember the `time_point` of the previous lap.